# Why MS Excel crashes and closes during Worksheet_Change Sub procedure?

Tags: excel, vba

I am having a problem with Excel crashing, when I run VBA code on an excel sheet.
I'm trying to add the following formula on worksheet change:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   Worksheets("testpage").Range("A1:A8").Formula = "=B1+C1"
End Sub
```

When this code is run i get a message saying "**excel has encountered a problem and needs to close**" and excel closes.

[image]

If I run the code in the `Worksheet_Activate()` procedure, it works fine and doesn't crash

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
   Worksheets("testpage").Range("A1:A8").Formula = "=B1+C1"
End Sub
```

But I really need it to work in the `Worksheet_Change()` procedure.

Has anyone experienced similar crashes when using the `Worksheet_Change()` event and can anyone point in the right direction to fix this issue ?

Comment: Code in a class does not "crash" there, but rather in the calling code.  Does "testpage" exist ?

Comment: Yes it exist, the error seems to only happen when i run the code in Worksheet_Change

Comment: Is Range("A1:A8") in the "testpage" sheet clean when you write the formula? There's no pivot table or anything like that already there? Also, just curious, why would you need to write the same formula in the same place after every change in a worksheet?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

I recommend this when using `Worksheet_Change`

1. You do not *need* the sheet name. In a Sheet Code Module, an unqualified Range reference refers to that sheet. That said, it is clearer to use the `Me` qualifier.  If you are trying to use another sheet, then qualify the range reference with that sheet.
2. Whenever you are working with `Worksheet_Change` event, always switch `Off` events if you are writing data to any cell. This is required so that the code doesn't retrigger the Change event, and go into a possible endless loop
3. Whenever you are switching off events, use error handling to turn it back on, else if you get an error, the code will not run the next time.

Try this

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error GoTo Whoa
    
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
    Me.Range("A1:A8").Formula = "=B1+C1"
    
Letscontinue:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Letscontinue
End Sub
```

Few other things that you may want to know when working with this event.

If you want to ensure that the code doesn't run when more than one cell is changed then add a small check

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    '~~> For Excel 2003
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    
    '
    '~~> Rest of code
    '
End Sub
```

The `CountLarge` was introduced in Excel 2007 onward because `Target.Cells.Count` returns an `Long` value which can error out in Excel 2007 becuase of increased total cells count.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    '~~> For Excel 2007
    If Target.Cells.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
    '
    '~~> Rest of code
    '
End Sub
```

To work with all the cells that were changed use this code

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim aCell As Range
    
    For Each aCell In Target.Cells
        With aCell
            '~~> Do Something
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

To detect change in a particular cell, use `Intersect`. For example, if a change happens in Cell `A1`, then the below code will fire

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Cell A1 was changed"
        '~~> Your code here
    End If
End Sub
```

To detect change in a particular set of range, use `Intersect` again. For example, if a change happens in range `A1:A10`, then the below code will fire

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A1:A10")) Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "one or more Cells in A1:A10 range was changed"
        '~~> Your code here
    End If
End Sub
```

**Note**: If you were getting an error earlier and you made the above changes and If your code is still not working then it is possible that the events have not been reset. In the `Immediate Window`, type `Application.EnableEvents = True` and press the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key. This will reset it to `True`. If you do not see the `Immediate Window`, the press the shortcut key <kbd>Ctl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> to launch the `Immediate Window`.

[image]

Comment: thanks Siddharth when i removed the sheet name it worked fine without any crashes

Comment: Gr8! I hope you switched off/on the events as well as suggested above?

Comment: No will i have to do that aswell ?

Comment: +1. One other good practice is to further limit the area whose change triggers the code by surrounding with something like: `If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D1:D8")) Is Nothing Then` ... `End If`. In this example, your code would only run if a cell in this range was changed.

Comment: @Siddharth, @Doug, why use `Range()` inside the Worksheet_Change function, instead of `Target.Parent.Range()`, which I would argue is more correct and safer?  `Range()` refers to the active sheet, which isn't necessarily the one that is being changed (e.g. if VBA code causes the change to this worksheet with another worksheet active).

Comment: @ErikEidt, I generally use Me.Range inside the event. But my testing confirms what Siddharth says in his answer, i.e., `Range` inside a Worksheet's Change event will refer to a range in that sheet, regardless of which sheet is active.

Comment: @Doug, ok thanks for that info.  I think you're right, even though according to msdn.micosoft.com, `When used without an object qualifier, this property is a shortcut for ActiveSheet.Range (it returns a range from the active sheet; if the active sheet isn’t a worksheet, the property fails).`  And we know that ActiveSheet doesn't necessarily change inside the event function to the changing sheet.  Guess the official docs are somewhat in error on this one.

Comment: @SiddharthRout - I think it's worth expanding on the use of `Intersect()` when checking `Target` against a desired range. I see many questions on SO where the issue was that the OP would just check `Intersect` was not `Nothing`, then go on to process the full `Target` range (which may well include cells outside of the desired range...)

Comment: Good Idea @TimWilliams! Will do it as soon as I can.

Answer (score 15):

Excel was crashing, not the VBA function.
The events were not disabled and the call stack was filled by an infinite loop of OnChange events.
A little advice that helps finding this type of errors: set a breakpoint on the first line of the event, then execute it step by step pressing F8.

Answer (score 0):

Also this solution is good:

```
Option Explicit
Private Busy As Boolean
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Busy Then
        Busy = True
        Range("A1:A8").Formula = "=B1+C1"
        Busy = False
    End If
End Sub
```